# Ребут при делении uint8_t

Tags: c

Имеется вот эта строчка:

`resDeep = ((60 + maxDeep) / maxDeep);`

resDeep и maxDeep - типа uint8_t
Если подставлять числа - всё работает правильно, но при использовании сами переменных RC-пульт перезагружается.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Надеюсь, maxDeep у вас всегда больше 0 и меньше 196?

Comment: Да, maxDeep меняется в диапазон от 1 до 100